# Simplenews newsletter url?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am working on a newsletter (GDPR).  I have a link to set on a scald image, I can display it in the template, the url is correct, but how can I set the link in the body ?

I mean, the whole message is displayed with a `print render($build);`

I can display the url with a `print($rgpd_url)`, but I will appear at the end of the email, not IN the message.

I thought of typing `[[[email]]]` on the html simplenews, and on the template a `str_replace`, and switching `[[[email]]]` with `$rgpd_url`.

But it is not working. So I think `str_replace` on the template is too late, I need to set this where the email is built. (In my opinion.)

Comment: It's GDPR. Welcome to SO! Please try to highlight code or token snippets to make your question easier to read. As it looks now it's quite unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: Sorry, in France it's RGPD :p
I need help to understand the way Simplenews build the email, and where it builds it, and if my problem is because you can't edit mail content in the template (in that case you need to edit its content where it is built.)